# Adding ORDER BY to LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

My pictures are out of order. In the `$t_adpics` table there's a `picid` AUTO_INCREMENT column. I want to use the `picid` ids to show images in the order from lowest to highest.

```
SELECT a.*, p.picid
FROM $t_ads a
LEFT OUTER JOIN $t_adpics p ON a.adid = p.adid
WHERE a.adid > 0
GROUP BY a.adid
ORDER BY a.adid DESC, p.picid ASC
```

So, I added `p.picid` in the SELECT part and then in the ORDER BY I added `p.picid ASC` but the images are still showing in whatever order.

Comment: Well you have to remove the first column if you don't want them ordered by that one... adding a second column as a secondary order won't do anything if you're already ordering by a unique value.

Comment: 'Show us some sample result, its current order, and the wanted order.

Comment: Hi, you do understand that the results will be sorted first by a.adid DESC and then by p.picid ASC ?

Comment: Note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is NEVER appropriate. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

In short, put p.picid into the first place in ORDER BY clause or leave it alone.

TLDR;
I doubt that LEFT OUTER JOIN is aplicable here if you want to sort list by pictures which is "on the right". I guess INNER JOIN would be more suitable here.
Also, GROUP BY looks wierd together with `SELECT *`. You can use only groupped fields or aggregates here.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `adid` is the primary key (or at least unique) for the `a` table.

You need an aggregation, perhaps `min()` or `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT a.*, MIN(p.picid) as picid
FROM $t_ads a LEFT OUTER JOIN
     $t_adpics p
     ON a.adid = p.adid
WHERE a.adid > 0
GROUP BY a.adid
ORDER BY a.adid DESC, p.picid ASC;
```

First, you have a problem with `picid` in the `SELECT` -- it is not part of the aggregation.  That is one error.

The `ORDER BY` is parsed *after* the `GROUP BY`. So this column is not available.

However, defining it using an aggregation function gets around this issue.

Comment: It seems plausible (likely, even) that this query would return an indeterminate result on non-aggregated columns of a.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . I made explicit my assumption that the id is unique or the primary key.

Comment: It seems an unlikely assumption.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Not at all.  First, it is consistent with the original syntax.  Second, in a table called `t_ads`, it is quite reasonable to name the primary key `adid`.

Comment: Primary keys are rarely 0 or less than 0